# Opening The Downloads Folder Of The Windows File Explorer

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm making a little program that when a jButton is clicked, it opens the downloads folder from the file explorer. I have the button set up, I'm just having troubles getting the folder open.

Here is my code.

```
    private void downloadsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

        String download = System.getenv("downloads");
        File downloadsDir = new File(download);

        try {
           Desktop.getDesktop().open(downloadsDir);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(GettingFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there an exception or something? Or is it just not opening?

Comment: @Compass, Take a look at this. http://tny.cz/1aeb50c5

Comment: So look at the value of `download` before the `new File()` call.  Print it out or look at it in a debugger.  You are aware, I suppose, that "downloads" is not a standard environment variable in Windows, so that unless you are setting that variable the result will be empty?

Comment: @arcy, "downloads" is just one of the names I tried to use. I couldn't find anything to tell me different. So, What should I use to get the Downloads folder in the File Explorer?

Comment: Depends on the version of windows.  You'll need to define how you want to figure this out for your program, how many versions of windows to support, etc. -- Win7 has a downloads folder under each user; I think XP had one for the whole machine but I don't remember for sure, etc.  I am not aware of an environment variable that will give this to you, sorry.

Comment: @arcy, This will probably just be a little thing for myself. Anyway, that's fine, I'll figure it out. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: The user.dir environment var will give you the user's home directory, then you could get Downloads off of that on win7.

Comment: @arcy, I'll mess around with it and see what I come up with!. :)